# R issue when moving an rmd file from one project to another (working directory issue)

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have two projects in R. I've moved an .Rmd document from project 1 to project 2.

When I used the .Rmd file which I had moved to project 2 to try and read in some data I get the following error message:

`cannot open file '"mydata.csv"': No such file or directoryError in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection`.

This kind of error usually suggests to me it's a working directory issue, however when I run getwd() in the command line it's the correct working directory that is listed and points to where the csv is stored. I've also run `getwd()` within the rmd doc and again the wd is correct.

Does anyone else have this experience of moving one .Rmd file to another project and then it not working in the new project?

The code in the .Rmd file that I am trying to run is:

`Data <- read.csv("mydata.csv", stringsAsFactors = T)` and the data is definitely within the project and has the correct title, is a csv etc.

Has anyone else seen this issue when moving an RMarkdown document into another project before?

Thanks

Comment: Is the path correct? Did you try doing Session -> Set Working Directory -> Source File Location

Comment: Yes tried that, I still get the same error message

Comment: Try printing `list.files(path)` and/or `list.files(path, pattern = 'mydata.csv')` within the Rmd just before the `read.csv` call, where `path` is the path to the folder where `mydata.csv` resides, let it be `.` if working directory. That way you can debug if the file really is located when Rmd file is knitted. If the file is located, then something funny is happening. If is not located, then check your previous code chunks in case you changed the working directory accidentally.

Comment: can you write out the full file path instead of simply  `read.csv("mydata.csv")`

Comment: Also - note that using `T` as an abbreviation for `TRUE` is dangerous as `T` can be used as a variable name. Try `T <- FALSE; stopifnot(T)` - that seems odd, but simply using T as a variable name also breaks it: `T <- rnorm(1); stopifnot(T)`

Answer (score 3):

This may not be the answer, but `rmarkdown` and `knitr` intentionally don't respect `setwd()`: the code in each block is run from the directory holding the `.rmd` file. So, if you've moved your `.rmd` file but are then using `setwd()` to change to the directory holding the data, that does not persist across code chunks.

If this is the issue, then one solution is to use the `knitr` options to set the `root.dir` to the data location:

```
opts_knit$set(root.dir = '/path/to/the/data')
```

See [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/277).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not relevant but it seems to be the most likely explanation for what's happening here:

The project shouldn't really interfere with your code here. When opening the project it will set your working directory to the root location of the project. However, this shouldn't matter in this case since `RMarkdown` files automatically set the working directory to the location where the `RMarkdown` file is saved. You can see this when running `getwd()` once in the `Console` and once from the `RMarkdown` file via `run current chunk`.

[image]

The behavior is the same when the file is knitted. So except in the case when `"mydata.csv"` is in the same directory as the `RMarkdown` file, the code above won't work.

There are two workarounds: you can use relative or absolute paths to navigate to your data file. In a project I prefer relative paths. Let's say the `rmd` file is in a folder called "scripts" and your data file is in a folder called "data" and both are in the same project folder. Then this should work:

```
Data <- read.csv("../data/mydata.csv", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

The other option, which I do not recommend, is to set the working diretory in the `rmd` file via:

```
opts_knit$set(root.dir = '../data/')
```

The reason why I wouldn't do that is because the working direcotry is only changed when knitting the document but using the `rmd` file interactivly, you have a different working directory (the location of the `rmd` file)

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not understand what was happening. Your explanation is way too clear.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great application of the here package for dealing with these types of issues.

here https://github.com/jennybc/here_here looks around the Rmd file (and all R files) for the .Rproj file and then uses that as an "anchor" to search for other files using relative references. If for instance you had the following project structure:

```
-data
|--mydata.csv
-src
|-00-import.R
|-01-make-graphs.R
|-02-do-analysis.R
-report
|--report.Rmd
-yourproject.Rproj
```

And you wanted to use mydata.csv in your report.Rmd you could do the following:

```
library(here)
dat <- read.csv(here("data", "mydata.csv"))
```

here will then convert this path to "~/Users/../data/mydata.csv" for you. Note that you have to be in the Rproject for this use case.

Here is such a great package and solves a lot of issues.